# When to delete socket with asio and async_accepet without using smart pointer?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

As I like to understand a code and to see the scope and the life of all the variables, I would like to be able to make a server using Asio with async calls without making use of smart pointer. However :

1. I can't shutdown the socket ("Bad file descriptor")
2. I can't close the socket (Segfault)
3. I can't delete the socket (Segfault too)

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

const char * const path = "/var/local/serv.socket";
asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor * acceptor;
asio::io_service io_service;

void handle_co(std::error_code ec){
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Connection !" << std::endl;
}

void loop(){
    auto socket = new asio::local::stream_protocol::socket(io_service);
    acceptor->async_accept(*socket, [&socket](std::error_code ec){
        handle_co(ec);
        std::cout<<socket->is_open() << std::endl; // 1 (true)
        socket->shutdown(asio::socket_base::shutdown_both, ec);
        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl; // Bad file descriptor
        socket->close(ec); // Segfault
        delete socket; // Segfault
        loop();
    });
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::remove(path);
    asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint endpoint(path);
    acceptor = new asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor(io_service);
    acceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor->bind(endpoint);
    acceptor->listen();
    loop();

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

How to edit is so that it works (without shared pointers) ?

Comment: Write it so it works with smart pointers (which is how it should be done anyway), then replace all calls to the smart pointer constructors and destructors with their inline code, ensuring they are all called at the correct times (hint: you can leave a scope in more than one way, so this isn't easy). Then, don't do that and use smart pointers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in lambda `[&socket]`. By capturing `socket` variable by alias you get reference to pointer which is in stack of `loop()` function (which already exitted when lambda get executed). So, you are calling close/shutdown on trash pointer. Just remove capturing by reference:

```
...
acceptor->async_accept(*socket, [socket](std::error_code ec){
...
```